# Change Angular HTTP response type

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

I'm using ionic framework 3.9 with angular 5.
When I'm sending a request to my backend, which is returning json, Angular is returning an `ArrayBuffer`.

Here is the code :

```
this.http.get(this.url, {responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(data => console.log(data);
```

And if I change

```
this.http.get
```

By

```
this.http.get<T>
```

or anything else, angular is giving me `HttpEvent<T>`.

So the response from the backend is JSON objects array.
How could I change the type of response given by httpclient ? I don't want an ArrayBuffer. I just want a classic array of objects.

Comment: `data.json()` should give you the JSON you want (without `{responseType: 'json'}`

Comment: What type do you specify for `T` in `this.http.get<T>`?

Comment: I tried this.http.get<any[]> and object[]. Günter, I've got this error : Error:(16, 63) TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` by default handles and returns an Observable of `json` objects already.

In your component as long as you are using `http: HttpClient` you will get a json response after any http method call. In order to map your json to a data model of your time you can use `map`.

Here's a dummy example

```
export class MyData {
  id: number,
  name: string

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

//in your component
export class myComponent {
  myData: MyData
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(someUrl).map(data => {
      this.myData = new MyData(data['id'], data['name'])
    }).subscribe();
  }
}
```

you can also do the mapping in `subscribe()` but I did it in map so that later if you have more operations to perform you can just chain.

Comment: If the shape of the JSON matches the shape of the data object, you can just cast it, without the need for the map operation, as in `this.http.get<MyData>(someUrl).subscribe(....)`

Comment: If it doesn't then OP has the option of choosing what goes where in `map()` like I showed here. Additionally if the api changes key then your cast would fail silently...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; 
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";

public myFunction(): void {
    this.getMyJsonArray().subscribe(data => 
        console.log(data);
    )
}

// Set the return type to an array of your object
private getMyJsonArray(): Observable<MyObject[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).catch(this._handleError);
}
private _handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
     return Observable.throw(err.error);
}
```

Comment: How does this help OP? Add some explanation as opposed to giving him more code to figure out...